# MySQL - REGEXP for matching a number preceded by '#' and NOT followed by another number

Tags: mysql, regex

As I think I've already explained in the title, I need a REGEXP pattern for selecting all rows in a table where on a specific column this pattern is met:

Character '#' followed by given number, eg. '5', must be present at least once, NOT followed by another number.

For instance, given number '5':

```
(#12+#55-#8)/#2 -> MUST NOT match the pattern.
(#12+#5-#8)/#2 -> MUST match the pattern.
(#12+#55-#5)/#2 -> MUST match the pattern.
```

Unfortunately I'm no regex expert and I've already wasted a few hours without much success.
Any help very welcome.

Comment: It can't happen. Since the numbers preceded by # char are IDs, the # char only indicates a new id is being inserted. The main problem is being sure I'm picking rows where a particular ID is present, so if I'm looking for '5', a string like '2-#51/#7' has to be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, the following would work:

`^.*?(#5)([^5]|$).*?$`

## Demo

Comment: Both solutions work, I'm accepting this one just because it came first (considering the first comment). Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem but be both careful, as this one will [fail if the `#5` is the end of the string](http://regex101.com/r/sR6gD9).

Answer (score 2):

You could use this pattern:

```
select * from table1
WHERE col1 REGEXP '#5([^0-9]|$)'
```

The idea is to find a `#5` followed by either not a number `[^0-9]` or the end of the string `$`.

See [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c027ea/1).